# Excel VBA - For next loop - find column number of displayed columns and result stored

Tags: excel, for-loop, calculated-columns, msgbox, vba

This is my first time asking a question, so please bear with me.

I have made a macro to hide columns in a named range based on a criteria using FOR-NEXT loop. The result always displays 2 columns.

With the resulting 2 columns, I make calculations.

I am facing problem to get the column number using vba of the resulting displayed columns and use them in the offset formula to make the calculations.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

```
Public Sub Custom_Report_Monthly()
On Error Resume Next

If Len(Range("Rpt_Type_M").Value) < 1 Then
MsgBox "Select Report Type"
GoTo ExitSub
ElseIf Len(Range("Select_Month").Value) < 1 Then
MsgBox "Select Month"
GoTo ExitSub
End If

ActiveSheet.Range("D_columns").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

If Range("Rpt_Type_M").Value = "Quantity" Then
   For Each c In Range("Titles")
   If c.Value = "Quantity" Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
   Next
ElseIf Range("Rpt_Type_M").Value = "Sales" Then
   For Each c In Range("Titles")
   If c.Value = "Sales" Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
   Next
ElseIf Range("Rpt_Type_M").Value = "Cost" Then
   For Each c In Range("Titles")
   If c.Value = "Cost" Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
   Next
ElseIf Range("Rpt_Type_M").Value = "Sales+Cost" Then
   For Each c In Range("Titles")
   If c.Value = "Sales" Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
   Next
   For Each c In Range("Titles")
   If c.Value = "Cost" Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
   Next
End If


For Each c In Range("P_Months")
   If Month(c.Value) <> Range("Select_Month_Num").Value Then
   c.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   End If
Next

For Each col In Range("D_columns") ' **this is the block where i am having problem**
   If col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
   MsgBox (Range("col").Column)
   End If
Next

Call Hide_Count_Columns
ExitSub:

End Sub
```

Comment: i have added it to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the column numbers to use them. Declare them first:

```
    Dim col As Object
    Dim intCol1 As Integer
    Dim intCol2 As Integer
```

Use this to get the variables

```
    For Each col In Range("D_columns").Columns
        If col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
            If intCol1 = 0 Then
                intCol1 = col.Column
            Else
                intCol2 = col.Column
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

If you need to pass the variables to Hide_Count_Columns, do it like this:

```
    Call Hide_Count_Columns(intCol1, intCol2)
```

Then you would declare the sub Hide_Count_Columns like this:

```
Sub Hide_Count_Columns(ByVal intCol1 As Integer, ByVal intCol2 As Integer)

'do something with column numbers

End Sub
```

Or if you do want to put the column numbers on the worksheet, you would create range names for them `intCol1` and `intCol1` Then put the column numbers there like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("intCol1").Value = intCol1
ActiveSheet.Range("intCol2").Value = intCol2
```

Comment: i have added the code now, can you help me in determining the column number in a for-next loop?

Comment: wow thanks. the next step is to store the column numbers in a identified cell or range. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot D_Bester. thumbs up!!